# Error rate of a class from confusion matrix

Tags: confusion-matrix

My professor gives a multiclass confusion matrix and asks for the *error rate of a certain class*. Unfortunately, the professor refuses to give a definition.

I think the closest value to an error rate for a class $j$ is the conditional probability $\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{Pred} \neq j ~|~ \mathrm{Truth} = j)$, i.e. the sum of the offdiagonal entries along the $j$-column divided by the sum of all the $j$-column entries. Do you agree?

(I guess the only alternative would be $\mathrm{P}(\mathrm{Truth} \neq j ~|~ \mathrm{Pred} = j)$, which is computed along the $j$-row.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is the definition that you're supposed to use, but usually in multiclass classification the most standard method to apply a binary classification measure is [one-vs-rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest): given a target class $C$ (positive class), consider all the other classes as a single negative class (i.e. as if they are all merged together).

According to this interpretation, the error rate of a target class $j$ would be the probability of an instance to have different predicted and true class, excluding cases where neither the predicted or true class is $j$ (these are not counted as errors since both the predicted and true class are "negative"),

Comment: Many thanks, @Erwan! Correct me if I am wrong: this is then the sum of all the entries along the $j$-row and $j$-column, excluding the diagonal entry, divided by the sum of the $j$-row and $j$-column, including the diagonal entry?

Comment: @Pippo: correct for the numerator, but the denominator should be the full sum of the matrix (i.e. total number of instances).